# Replace nested for loop with list comprehension in Python

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Given a list of integers `c`, I want to perform the following:

1. Count how many elements of `c` are less than index `i`, where `i` is from `0` to `len(c)`.
   For example: `c=[1, 0, 2, 1]`, then the output to the above will be `b=[1, 3, 4, 4]` because only the `1` element of `c` is less than or equal to `i=0`, then there are `3` elements of `c` less than or equal to `i=1`,  then there are `4` elements of `c` less than or equal to `i=2`, and lastly there are `4` elements of `c` less than or equal to `i=3`.
2. Find `a=[b[0] b[1]-1 b[2]-2 ... ]`
3. Find `math.prod(a)`

---

I manage to do it using nested for loops, but I am learning the list comprehensions and want to transform them into nested for loops inside the list comprehensions.

```
#this code works
def solve(c):
    a=1
    for i in range(len(c)):
        a=a*(sum(element<=i for element in c)-i)
    return(a)
#input c=[1, 0, 2, 1]
#output 4
```

But this one fails:

```
$this code does not work
def solve(c):
    a=1
    return([(a=a*(sum(element<=i for element in c)-i)) for i in range(len(c))])
```

Comment: Having an assignment inside the list comprehension doesn't make sense, and you don't seem to be using `math.prod` at all. Start smaller, try making `b` with a list comprehension or converting `[1, 2, 2, 1]` to `4` with `math.prod`, then put the pieces together.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `b=[sum(element<=i for element in c) for i in range(len(c))]`

Comment: Great, keep going, step by step.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks, I got the answer now. `a=[(b[i]-i) for i in range(len(c))]` and then `return(math.prod(a))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[[item for item in c if item <= ind] for ind in range(len(c))]` give you the list of item that are < for the index.

`[len([item for item in c if item <= ind]) - ind for ind in range(len(c))]` will give you your second point.